# Surefire does not actually run tests

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

My Maven project uses the Surefire plugin to execute tests. The application is written with Spring Boot. I don't use the Spring Boot parent - I want to use another parent - but I imported the *spring-boot-dependencies*. Tests are written with JUnit, and I have *junit-jupiter-api*, *junit-jupiter-engine* and *spring-test* on my classpath.

One of the tests is a very simple `ExampleTest` that lives in *src/test/java*:

```java
package it.mulders.brainfuckjvm.demoapp;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void yes() {
        assertThat(true).isTrue();
    }
    @Test
    public void no() {
        assertThat(true).isFalse();
    }
}
```

When I run `mvn clean test --pl demo-app -Dtest=ExampleTest -X`, this test is not ran.

Because I added `-X`, I have very verbose logging, and the Surefire booter JAR and config files are not deleted afterwards. So I inspect *surefire3290618242954546634tmp*, to find:

```
#surefire
#Thu Apr 16 11:11:50 CEST 2020
tc.0=it.mulders.brainfuckjvm.demoapp.ExampleTest
pluginPid=8240

...
(tens of lines omitted for brevity)
...

providerConfiguration=org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
```

This all seems fine. It detects the test that I want to run, and it looks familiar to another module in the same project that does **not** use Spring Boot. That module **does** execute its tests. However, the logging is this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo-app ---

...

[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------

...

[DEBUG] Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /path/to/brainfuck-jvm/demo-app && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -jar /path/to/brainfuck-jvm/demo-app/target/surefire/surefirebooter7731933888241020050.jar /path/to/brainfuck-jvm/demo-app/target/surefire 2020-04-16T11-11-49_920-jvmRun1 surefire3290618242954546634tmp surefire_03070161998729763620tmp
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

For reference, the whole project can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/mthmulders/brainfuck-jvm/tree/improvement/fix-test-setups). The module that runs fine is *language*, the one that does not is *webapp*. Note that you'd need GraalVM to run the tests.

Comment: Made a pull request against your repo. The problem is that spring-boot and the rest of the application used different versions of JUnit Jupiter ...You have to be sure to make a dependencyManagement import before Spring Boot Dependencies otherwise you get the one from Spring Boot which is a different version which results in issues. I have run with JDK 8 (not Graal) that shows there is a unit test failure ...Just take a look at the PR...

Comment: Thanks for the PR and the explanation. The explanation makes total sense, so I'd be more than willing to accept it as an answer ;-).